# Regex replace recursive with one pattern

Tags: php, arrays, regex

`$array[key][key]...[key]`
replace to
`$array['key']['key']...['key']`

I managed only to add quotes to the first keyword of the array.

`\$([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\[([a-zA-Z_-]+[0-9]*)\]` replace to `\$\1\[\'\2\3\'\]`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I edited the question, please see again.

Comment: You can do some context-sensitive lookups with lookbehinds `(?<!")`. But if this is really about fixing *all* your unquoted keys, and *fully automated* for a whole codebase, then you're gonna have to look into the PHP tokenizer for rewriting.

Comment: @SeviDavidov Why not just: https://regex101.com/r/aL8wA3/1 ?

Comment: What about such a regex: [`(\$\w+|(?!^)\G)\[([^]]*)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/oW1zW2/1)?

Comment: If always like this [try str_replace](https://eval.in/421138): `$str = str_replace(array("[","]"), array("['","']"), $str);`

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex that does not perform a *recursive*, but *consecutive* matching:

```
$re = '/(\$\w+|(?!^)\G)\[([^]]*)\]/'; 
$str = "\$array[key][key][key]";
$subst = "$1['$2']"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/8QNk1k)

The regex `(\$\w+|(?!^)\G)\[([^]]*)\]` matches all square parenthetical substrings (capturing their contents into Group 2) (with `\[([^]]*)\]`) that either are right after a `'$'+alphanumerics` substring (due to the `\$\w+` part) or that follow one another consecutively (thanks to `(?!^)\G`).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't need anything fancy, just get the stuff you need then
replace in a callback.

Untested:

```
$new_input = preg_replace_callback('/(?i)\$[a-z]+\K(?:\[[^\[\]]*\])+/',
        function( $matches ){
             return preg_replace( '/(\[)|(\])/', "$1'$2", $matches[0]);
        },
        $input );
```